# Pinterest Addtocart event code | Shopify | Turbo Theme

Tags: ajax, shopify

I'm trying to set up Pinterest conversion tracking codes, so I just pasted a Pinterest base tag & Checkout Event to the theme.liquid file & checkout settings, however, I also want to add the Add To Cart event code, but I was not able to do it with the help of the official instructions since I couldn't find a line of code where I needed to pass the Add to Cart code. Can anyone tell me exactly where I should paste the code?

Instructions that I was looking at were these (Step 3) : 
https://help.pinterest.com/en/business/article/shopify-and-pinterest-tag

In my current code that I have in my product.liquid I couldn't find addtocart section where I need to input the Pinterest code.  FYI I'm using the ***TURBO THEME***.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Online Store -> Themes -> YOUR THEME -> Actions -> Edit Code -> in the left sidebar find "Snippets" -> **product-form.liquid** file

and then you can find button with **add_to_cart** class and add this onclick="pintrk('track', 'addtocart');" in the end of the tag <button **here**>